# Solution of a linearly constrained quadratic programming problem

Tags: reference-request, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

What is the solution of the following optimization problem:

\begin{align}
&\min{\mathbf{p}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{B} \mathbf{p}}\\
&\text{subject to}: \mathbf{0}\leq{\mathbf{p}}\leq \mathbf{1}.
\end{align}
where ${\mathbf{p}}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{B}$ is a symmetric matrix with the elements $b_{ij}\in\{0,+1,-1\}$. Note that $\mathbf{B}$ is not a non-negative definite matrix.

Are there any closed form or approximate solutions? How about upper or lower bounds for the optimal value? (Numerical methods are not desirable!)

Comment: Sorry, you can't get out of a numerical solution on this one.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Depends on what we mean by "numerical". The minimum has rational coordinates and can be computed exactly in finite time.

Comment: Thst is true for all linear or quadratic programs with rational coefficients. But given he asked for "closed form or approximate" solutions it is safe to suppose that a simplex algorithm is not what he seeks.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I need a exact or approximate solution/bound in closed form, to use the results in another problem. Also, if you can suggest a numerical solution that achieves the global optimum (not local ones), it would be so helpful for me.

Comment: @MichaelGrant do you have a reference for your statement "This is true for all linear or quadratic programs with rational coefficients."?